# How do I remove a local SSL Certificate?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, mamp

While testing locally with MAMP, I created a dummy SSL certificate for testing some https URLs. I referenced this walkthrough: https://gist.github.com/jfloff/5138826. The following steps are relevant to creating the SSL cert:

```
$ cd ~

# generate a private key (will request a password twice)
$ openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024

# generate certificate signing request (same password as above)
$ openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr

# Answer the questions
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]: CA
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]: Quebec
Locality Name (eg, city) []: Montreal
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]: Your Company
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []: Development
Common Name (eg, YOUR name) []: localhost
Email Address []: your_email@domain.com
A challenge password []: # leave this empty
An optional company name []: # leave this empty

# generate the certificate
$ openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt

# remove the password from the server key
$ cp server.key server.tmp
$ openssl rsa -in server.tmp -out server.key

# Move the certificate into your MAMP apache configuration folder
$ cp server.crt /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache
$ cp server.key /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache
```

But ever since creating it, I've encountered unexpected issues when alternating between http and https URLs.

**What I've tried**:

- Uninstalling MAMP
- Deleting the relevant cert files (server.key, server.csr, server.crt, server.tmp)

But neither approach fixed the problem. How do I go about undoing this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.